# Make code less complex and more readable

Tags: python, regex, string, code-complexity

I need to rewrite my simple code. I'm getting simple strings as below:

- Distrib ABC 1-2-x
- Distrib ABC DEF 1-2-x
- Distrib ABC DEF GHI 1-2-x

I'm getting to .split() all words after "Distrib " and I've to fulfill following conditions:

1. If string[0] is text && string[1] is as integer then join only these to get as result "ABC/1"
2. If string[0] is text && string[1] is text join only them and then get as result "ABC/DEF"
3. If string[0] is text && string[1] is text && string[2] is text join them all and get as result: "ABC/DEF/GHI"

I wrote a simple code to do this but I'm really interested how to write it less complex and more readable ;)

```
import re

def main_execute():
    #input_text = "Distrib ABC 1-2-x"
    #input_text = "Distrib ABC DEF 1-2-x"
    #input_text = "Distrib ABC DEF GHI 1-2-x"

    print(str(input_text))
    load_data = re.search('\s[A-Z]*.[A-Z]*.[A-Z]+ [0-9]', input_text).group()
    print("Pobrany ciąg znaków: " + load_data)

    words_array = load_data.split()

    if re.match('[0-9]', words_array[1]):
        print("Złożony ciąg: "
              + words_array[0]
              + "/"
              + words_array[1])
        elif re.match('[A-Z]', words_array[0]) and re.match('[A-Z]', words_array[1]) and re.match('[0-9]', words_array[2]):
        print("Złożony ciąg: "
              + words_array[0]
              + "/"
              + words_array[1])
    elif re.match('[A-Z]', words_array[0]) and re.match('[A-Z]', words_array[1]) and re.match('[A-Z]', words_array[2]) and re.match('[0-9]', words_array[3]):
        print("Złożony ciąg: "
              + words_array[0]
              + "/"
              + words_array[1]
              + "/"
              + words_array[2])


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main_execute()
```

Comment: Maybe a good post for [codereview.se]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be vastly simplified to

```
import re

data = """
Distrib ABC 1-2-x
Distrib ABC DEF 1-2-x
Distrib ABC DEF GHI 1-2-x
"""

rx = re.compile(r'Distrib (\w+) (\w+)\s*((?:(?!\d)\w)+)?')

results = ["/".join([n for n in m.groups() if n]) for m in rx.finditer(data)]
print(results)
```

Which yields

```
['ABC/1', 'ABC/DEF', 'ABC/DEF/GHI']
```

See a demo for the expression [**on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Li8p2f/1).

---

Another approach, as proposed by @Wiktor, could be

```
Distrib (\w+) (\w+)\s*([^\W\d]+)?
```

The part `[^\W\d]+` is saying: not not (the doubling is no mistake!) word characters, not digits, as long as possible.

Comment: Great! Thank you :)

Comment: You may further simplify it to `r'Distrib (\w+) (\w+)\s*([^\W\d]+)?'`

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Jan's answer, you can make the regex easier to read with:

```
import re

data = """
Distrib ABC 1-2-x
Distrib ABC DEF 1-2-x
Distrib ABC DEF GHI 1-2-x
"""

rx = re.compile(r'Distrib ([A-Z]+) ([A-Z0-9]+) ?([A-Z]*)')

results = ["/".join([n for n in m.groups() if n]) for m in rx.finditer(data)]
print(results)
```

which gives the same result:

```
['ABC/1', 'ABC/DEF', 'ABC/DEF/GHI']
```